# Email confirmation Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

My user can't use the application without confirming his email. Thus, I put him into a screen that make him wait for the email confirmation.

The problem is that I'm not getting any feedback from the Auth Listener when the user confirm his email.

I tried to create a pulling mechanism from the currentUser info, however it seems to me a look cache keep this information outdated.

I'm using firebase javascript API.

```
registerUserListener() {
    return ConfigRepo.getInstance().FirebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      console.log('splash - registerUserListener', user);
      if (user) {
        if (user.emailVerified) {
          //It's  not called
        }
      } else {
          //It's  not called
      }
    });
  }
```

also doesn't work

```
FirebaseApp.auth().currentUser()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for it using the User API.

> reload reload() returns firebase. Promise containing void
>
> Refreshes the current user, if signed in.
>
> Returns non-null firebase.Promise containing void

It forces the user to update himself.